# wechat ui: Routing not working if element id is not original(页面跳转只能用预设id？）

Tags: javascript, user-interface, routes, wechat

If I didn't get it wrong, routing of wechat UI page depends on

```
 <a href="#/button"></a>
```

and

```
   <script type="text/html" id="tpl_button"></script>
```

But when I apply them to my scenario it won't work. Eventually I found out that even I only make a little change to the above code in the original `index.html` file, like changing both `button` to `buton`, the routing will stop working. When `<a>` is clicked, an error saying `url not found` shows up in the console.
Really strange, what could be the possible cause?

Chinese version of the question just in case:
[image]

Comment: What the earth do you want, then? Such an error is very normal, I wonder why that is strange. 你究竟想怎样？这个错误非常正常，我不明白为何奇怪。

Comment: I just want to change the `id`s to my own, such as `choose` or `mybutton`

Comment: Then it must be the codes in javascript which blocks you from doing so. Give up your idea please.